# merge/update records in snow flake using snow pipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

just a small helpI am looking for how to update the data in snowflake using Snow pipe.
While searching I found these two links which are old .
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008RPe1MSAT/how-to-setup-snowpipe-that-it-updates-inserts-the-row-values-in-the-table-according-to-primarykeys
https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/question/0D50Z00008SNJECSA5/performing-an-upsert-with-snowpipe
So just want to know is there are any new updates in snow pipe to support Merge records and Schema also (our table schemas change dynamically after every update).

at present we are using data bricks and Delta tables and we want to continue to use data bricks along with snowflake

Here I am finding only below options to  update records in to snowflake

1)full overwrite every time
2)create a temp table for each table in snowflake and do merge in snowflake (I need to overwrite the temp table every time)

We are searching for different solutions to do this in most efficient way ,  Please share your thoughts / suggestions to do it in better way